# node.js for loop doesen't loop with the continue command

Tags: node.js, loops

The goal of the code is repeat the loop till the array index shows something greater than -1. But for some reason the loop stops after one run. And prints -1.

```
var Darray = ["Dienstag, 19.3.2019:","Donnerstag, 21.3.2019:", "Montag, 18.3.2019:", "Mittwoch, 20.3.2019:", "Montag, 25.3.2019:"];

var x = 1;
var y = 1;
var z = 2019;

loop: for (x = 1; x < 32; x++) {
  var suchen = Darray.indexOf(`Montag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
  var suchen = Darray.indexOf(`Dienstag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
  var suchen = Darray.indexOf(`Mittwoch, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
  var suchen = Darray.indexOf(`Donnerstag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
  var suchen = Darray.indexOf(`Freitag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
  if (x == 30) {
    y++
  }
  if (y == 12) {
    z++
  }
  if(suchen == -1) {
    continue loop;       
  }
};

console.log(suchen)
```

Comment: Could you update your answer with a better description of what you want this code to achieve? I already see several problems that I could address in an answer but I would like clarification on what the code should be doing at a high level.

Comment: why do you assign var suchen multiple times? it seems to be wrong

Comment: The purpose of the code is to loop over and ove again till the index number from Darray is 0 or greater. It should be more or less a loop that looks for the strings in the array. Since the date will always change in the array, the only thing that stays the same are the weekdays: Monday, Friday... in german Monday. x.y.z: these are the vales for the date. In short the main goal is to do a loop till it find a string in the array for example the string "Dienstag, 19.3.2019:" and the Problem is it will only do one run and not a loop. I hope it's more clearer now.

Comment: The loop is supposted to try every date combination in and check till it finds the right one in the array. First: 1.1.2019, 2.1.2019,...1.2.2019. So Monday, 1.1.2019:,... Monday, 1.2.2019

Comment: But why do you assign var suchen multiple times like was previously mentioned?  Your only actually doing checks with the last one?  Additionally, y is only incremented twice and z is never incremented so your probably exiting because your not checking every case?

Answer (score -1):

I got my code working, thanks for comment about the var suchen, was a little bit sleepy yesterday. New working code:

```
loop: for (x = 1; x < 32; x++) {
var date = `${x}.${y}.${z}`
console.log(date)
var mon = Darray.indexOf(`Montag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
var die = Darray.indexOf(`Dienstag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
var mit = Darray.indexOf(`Mittwoch, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
var don = Darray.indexOf(`Donnerstag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);
var fre = Darray.indexOf(`Freitag, ${x}.${y}.${z}:`);

if (mon != -1 || die != -1 || mit != -1 || don != -1 || fre != -1) {
    break; 
} 
else if (mon == -1 || die == -1 || mit == -1 || don == -1 || fre == -1) {
    if (x == 31) {
        y++
        var x = 0;
    } 
    if (y == 12) {
        z++
        var y = 1;

    }

    continue loop;       
}
}

console.log(mon, die, mit, don, fre)
```

Any way to write if condition better looking?